# Как экспортировать функцию из одного файла в другой на Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Кусочек функции которую пытаюсь экспортировать

```
var Foo = function(dir, pathToFile){
    let Mode = require('stat-mode'); // проверка дириктори или файл
    let temp; //вспомогательная переменная 
    let jsonFile = { 
        table: []
     };
..............
}
```

Делаю экспорт

```
module.exports = Foo;
```

Импортирую так

```
const foo = require("../index.js");
```

Вызов функции

```
foo(dir, 'data/firstScreen.json');
```

Как результат я получаю ошибку

```
foo(dir, 'data/firstScreen.json');
TypeError: foo is not a function
```

Вот ссылки на код из моих файлов
pastebin.com/9sAqN878 index.js pastebin.com/ap9PKZYN routes.js

Answer (score 1):

> Вот ссылки на код из моих файлов pastebin.com/9sAqN878 index.js
> pastebin.com/ap9PKZYN routes.js

`index.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const todoRoutes = require('./routes/routes');
var Foo = function(dir, pathToFile){}
module.exports = Foo;
```

`routes.js`

```
const {Router} = require('express');
const router = Router();
const foo = require("../index.js");
...
var myModule = require('../index.js');
```

Что же мы видим? - [циклическую зависимость](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles).

Что же происходит?

> a.js грузит b.js В этот момент b.js пытается загрузить a.js. Для
> того, чтобы предотвратить зацикливание, незавершенная копия объекта
> exports из a.js возвращается в модуль b.js, затем загрузка b.js
> завершается, и его exports объект передается модулю a.js.

Вам, вероятно, лучше реструктурировать свой код так, чтобы не возникала циклическая зависимость. Может быть, создать третий файл, который используется двумя другими.