# Помогите разобраться с модулями в nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

До недавнего времени с js вопросов не возникало, однако недавно возник такой вопрос который вогнал меня в ступор, пытаясь использовать js как ООП я столкнулся с некой проблемой.
К примеру у меня есть файл запуска всего проекта с названием main.js, вот собственно сам код как пример:

```
//main.js
const User = require('./user');
console.log('User',User.maxCounts)
class Main {
    static users = 1
}
module.exports = Main;
```

В данном случае файл main.js является точкой входа в программу и мы обращаемся к классу User, который находится в другом файле, к примеру нам нужно получить какие-то параметры с этого класса и тут всё хорошо, мы получаем ответ.
Теперь переходим к файлу user.js и при инициализации данного класса нам необходимо запросить какие-то значения/параметры у главного класса Main:

```
//user.js
const Main = require('./main');
class User {
    static maxCounts = 50
}
console.log('Main users',Main.users)
module.exports = User;
```

вот тут и возникает проблема, мне необходимо получить какую-то общую информацию с главного класса, будь то массив или объект или что либо ещё, но т.к файл user был инициализирован с файла main нам выдает undefined:

```
//in console
Main users undefined
User 50
```

т.к по сути файл main остановил свое выполнение на строке const User = require('./user') и пока не пройдет полная инициализация класса User мы не можем обратиться к классу Main. Как следствие выходит циклический запрос где Main требует класс User, а User требует класс Main который еще не инициализирован как я понимаю.. подскажите как решить данную проблему или может у меня сложилось не правильное представление о ООП в целом, т.к для меня каждый класс должен содержать параметры относящееся к своему классу.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, при циклических зависимостях неполная загрузка модуля предотвращает бесконечный цикл: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles Там же говорится, что это нужно учитывать при планировании архитектуры зависимостей.

Comment: я писал о циклических зависимостях тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1184703/2659

Answer (score 0):

Это решается довольно просто, если принять за философию архтектурный подход как некий комплекс:

1. В вашем приложении имеется несколько `JavaScript` библиотек, которые не должны ничего знать об объектах и состоянии основного приложения, практически как в функциональном программировании (используем аргументы в сигнатуре функций в качестве передачи параметров). Каждый новый `js-файл` - это ваш изолированный модуль (синглтон), где вы можете реализовать собственный объект и вернуть его состояние.
2. Основная точка входа (оно же ядро приложения), организовано как связующее звено всех `JavaScript` библиотек как компонентов дополняющих приложение, делегируя процессы / состояния и т.п. из основного приложения методам данных библиотек. Эдакий собственный фреймворк.
3. Далее можете продумать по структуре директорий и т.п.

В целом, принципы ООП можно вложить в каждом модуле отдельно разделив их на ответственности. Находясь в некоем кругу Node.js разработчиков, мы пришли к мнению что лучше всего подключать все необходимые `js-библиотеки` в одном файле, при запуске проекта, так как Node.js запоминает пути этих библиотек и кеширует их. Тоесть если библиотека будет подключена дважды из разных директорий, она закешируется несколько раз и это съест хоть и небольшую но часть памяти.

Вот как это можно реализовать:

```js
// user.js
class User {
    static maxCounts = 50
}

module.exports = User;
```

```js
// main.js
class Main {
    static users = 1;
}

module.exports = Main;
```

```js
// index.js
const Main = require('./main');
const User = require('./user');

console.log('Main users', Main.users);
console.log('User', User.maxCounts);
```

```bsh
# точка входа
node index.js
```